# Dereferencing a 3 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dereference

```
#include "stdio.h"


int main(){

int D[2][3][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};


printf("D: %p\n", D);
printf("*(0x0061FEC8): %d\n", *((int *)(0x0061FEC8)));
printf("*D: %p\n", *D);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
D: 0061FEC8
*(0x0061FEC8): 1
*D: 0061FEC8
```

p.s : I obtained the address 0x0061FEC8 by running the code several times and saw that it is not changing. Since dereferencing an integer is not allowed, I also casted it into integer pointer.

OK, I read at several sources that with two exceptions of & and sizeof operators, names of the multidimensional arrays decay into pointers to the first element of that contigious memory block. **So, if the 3d array name D decays into the pointer to the first element, why the outputs of the 2nd and 3rd lines are different?** D should be decaying into the address 0x0061FEC8 and dereferencing this address should give value 1 in my opinion. However, it prints the address again.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing `*((int *)(0x0061FEC8))`? Just don't do stuff like that!

Comment: With `ASLR` (address space layout randomization), you can't guarantee the fixed address [so don't do it in real code]. But, the third `printf` should use `%d` and _not_ `%p`

Comment: If `D` were a 1D array, then dereferncing is a pointer to the first integer element. But it is a 3D array, and dereferncing it points to the first of its two 2D arrays.

Comment: @CraigEstey replacing %p with %d, just prints the decimal equivalent of the address

Comment: @muyustan Um, yes. It derefed `D` but I spaced out on `D` being 3D. OP's question was why 2nd and 3rd where different and the format was different. I assumed OP had got the deref correct and only the format was wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you do `*((int *)(0x0061FEC8))` you treat the address at that location as a pointer to the first elements of a ***1D*** array. When you dereference that pointer you get the value at that location.

But when you do `*D` then it's the same as `D[0]`, which has the type `int [3][3]`. It will decay to a pointer to `D[0][0]`, which has the type `int (*)[3]`. I.e. `*D` is not a value.

So the two expressions do two very different things. One (the first) is wrong, and the second is correct.